# Union data type field behavior

Tags: c

I am having trouble figuring out how this piece of code works.
Mainly, I am confused by how does x.br get the value of 516 after x.str.a and x.str.b get their values of 4 and 2, respectively.
I am new to unions, so maybe there is something I am missing, but shouldn't there only be 1 active field in an union at any given time?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(short num, short* res) {
    if (num) {
        *res = *res * 10 + num % 10;
        f(num / 10, res);
    }
}
typedef union {
    short br;
    struct {
        char a, b;
    } str;
} un;
void main() {
    short res = 0; un x;
    x.str.a = 4;
    x.str.b = 2;
    f(x.br, &res);
    x.br = res;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", x.br, x.str.a, x.str.b);
}
```

I would be very thankful if somebody cleared this up for me, thank you!

Comment: regarding: `void main() {`  regardless of some compilers, like visual studio, will allow, this is not a valid signature for `main()`  The valid signatures are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Notice they all have a return type of `int`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `struct 
    {
        char a, b;
    } str;`  Most debuggers use the struct 'tag' name to be able to access the fields within the struct.  Therefore, strongly suggest adding a 'tag' name to that struct

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Deepstop answer, and to correct an important point about your understanding -

> shouldn't there only be 1 active field in an union at any given time?

There's no such a thing as **active field** in unions. All the different fields are referring to the same exact piece of memory (except miss-aligned data.

You can look at the different fields as different ways to interpret the same data, i.e. you can read your union as two fields or 8 bits or one field of 16 bits. But both will always "work" at the same time.

Comment: Crystal clear now, I previously thought that I needed to initialize another field which would just overwrite all the other ones. Now I understand that it is just the same memory block. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Stefan12 C and C++ are different here. The union trick in your code is known as "type punning", which is supported by C but not C++. This alone is why C++ is unsuitable for hardware-related programming.

Answer (score 1):

OK short is likely a 16 bit integer. Char a, b are each 8 bit chars.

So you are using the same 16 bit memory location for both.

```
0000 0010 0000 0100 is the 16 bit representation of 516
0000 0010           is the 8 bit representation of 2
          0000 0100 is the 8 bit representation of 4
```

The CPU you are running this on is 'little-endian' so the low-order byte of a 16 bit integer comes first, which is the 2, and the high order byte, the 4, comes second.

So by writing 2 then 4 into consecutive bytes, and reading them back as a 16 bit integer, you get 516, which is 2 * 256 + 4. If you wrote 3 then 5, you'd get 3 * 256 + 5, which is 783.

The point is that union puts two data structures in exactly the same memory location.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks for the thorough explanation! Just one question, if br was an integer, would a and b be stored in the first two bytes?

Comment: Do note that this is undefined behavior. Like you said, only one member may be 'active' at one time. The compiler will let you read from the other member, but the result is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @alex - this is wrong. This is not undefined behavior.

Comment: Stefan if br were an integer (32 bits), then a & b would be the low order bytes, so the result would still be 516. Some CPU architectures are 'big endian', where the high order bytes come first, so the results would be completely different. It is up to the programmer to account for that, or to make sure that the code only runs on little-endian machines (like the Intel CPUs)

Comment: By the way, Stanford U has a computer science course, I think it is called 'data structures', which is on iTunes university (and maybe elsewhere), which goes into this stuff in gory detail. It uses union a lot to illustrate how computers store data, and is amazingly detailed.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I will definitely give it a look!

Answer (score 1):

> how does x.br get the value of 516 after x.str.a and x.str.b get their
>   values of 4 and 2

Your union definition

```
typedef union {
    short br;
    struct {
        char a, b;
    } str;
} un;
```

Specifies that `un.br` share the same memory address as `un.str`. This is the whole point of a union. This means that when you modify the value of `un.br` that you are also modifying the values for `un.str.a` and `un.str.b`.

> I am new to unions, so maybe there is something I am missing, but
>   shouldn't there only be 1 active field in an union at any given time?

Not sure what you mean by "only be 1 active field", but the members of a union are all mapped to the same memory address so any time that you write a value to a union member it writes that value to the same memory address as the other members. If you want the members to be mapped to different memory addresses so that when you write the value of a member it only modifies the value of that specific member, then you should use a `struct` and not a `union`.

Comment: "Active field" is a property of unions in C++. There is no such restriction in C.

Comment: I meant as in entering a new value to some field would overwrite what was in the previous ones. For example, if I had two fields, char str[5]; and int i; if I put something in the string and afterwards initialize i, if I try to print str it wouldn't have the original string if I'm not mistaken.